# Angular/Aggrid: how to use component function in a separate component (No relationship)

Tags: angular, httpclient, ag-grid

I am using the grid api, ag-grid. To send data to the grid, a variable called `rowData` is created in the component class. In this `TableComponent`, I have a function `refreshData`. This function uses a service to get data form the server, then display it to the grid:

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  private rowData: any;
  private columnDefs;

  constructor(
    private service: Service,
    private http: HttpClient,
    vcr: ViewContainerRef,
    public dialog: MatDialog, 
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.columnDefs = [{
        headerName: 'id',
        field: 'id',
        hide: true
      },
      {
        headerName: 'First Name',
        field: 'firstName'
      }
    ];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.refreshData();
  }

  refreshData() {
    this.service.getData('http://localhost:3000/employees')
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.rowData = data;
      })
  }

}
```

I have a separate component that creates a form. When I click a button in my `TableComponent`, the form pops up. From here, the user can click a save button to save their data to the grid. Here is the service, and component:

**Service**

```
getData(url: string): Observable < any > {
  return this.http.get(url).pipe(
    map(this.extractData),
    catchError(this.handleErrorObservable));
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res;
  console.log(res)
  return body || {};
}

saveUser(employee: Employees) {
  return this.http.post(this._url, employee, httpOptions).subscribe((res: any) => {
    res = employee
    this.getData('http://localhost:3000/employees')
  })
}
```

**Component Save**

```
employeeInfo: Employees; //my model

onSave() {
  this.employeeInfo = this.frmUser.getRawValue();
  this.service.saveUser(this.employeeInfo);
  //Here I would somehow refresh the data
  this.dialogRef.close({
    success: 'success'
  });
}
```

Now the way I refresh my table is by using an interval function in my `TableComponent` class. This just does the function `refresData` ever few seconds to fetch the data and update the table. But this is not good practice, as my app is constantly making http requests when it does not have to.

**Question: How can I use my refreshData function inside my `FormComponent` class?** I would like the `rowData` variable to be updated every time I click the save button. Is this possible with `EventEmitters`? The form is completely separate from my `TableComponent`, so I do think that is possible. Thank you.

Okay I figured it out!
**service: **

```
private componentMethodCallSource = new Subject<any>();

componentMethodCalled$ = this.componentMethodCallSource.asObservable();

saveUser(employee: Employees) {
  return this.http.post(this._url, employee, httpOptions).subscribe((res: any) => {
    res = employee
    this.componentMethodCallSource.next();
  })
}
```

**TableComponent**

```
constructor() {


  this.service.componentMethodCalled$.subscribe(
    () => {
      this.refreshData()
    }
  )
}
```

I created observables, subscribe to one in my constructor and apply this.refreshData to it. Then thanks to my service, I can call the observable inside my saveData service. Then, I just call the saveData service in my form class.

Comment: Why not create a BehaviorSubject in the service and then subscribe to it in both the components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Subject`/`BehaviorSubject` in your service. Inside the `extractData` method in your service, call the `next` method on this `Subject`/`BehaviorSubject` that you just declared.

Then in your `TableComponent` just subscribe to this `Subject`/`BehaviorSubject`. You'll get the updated values each time there's a change.

So here's what I mean:

```
employees: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

getData(url: string): Observable < any > {
  return this.http.get(url).pipe(
    map(this.extractData),
    catchError(this.handleErrorObservable));
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res;
  console.log(res)
  // Assuming that body here has an array of Employee Objects.
  employees.next(body);
  return body || {};
}

saveUser(employee: Employees) {
  return this.http.post(this._url, employee, httpOptions).subscribe((res: any) => {
    res = employee
    this.getData('http://localhost:3000/employees')
  })
}
```

Now in your `TableComponent` instead of calling the `Service`'s `getData` method, just call `subscribe` on `service.employees` like so:

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  private rowData: any;
  private columnDefs;

  constructor(
    private service: Service,
    private http: HttpClient,
    vcr: ViewContainerRef,
    public dialog: MatDialog, 
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.columnDefs = [{
        headerName: 'id',
        field: 'id',
        hide: true
      },
      {
        headerName: 'First Name',
        field: 'firstName'
      }
    ];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.employees.subscribe(employees => this.rowData = employees);
    this.service.getData();
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Two problems. 1: when using your implementation, my getData service is not being called, so when I subscribe to the behavior subject, employees in my ngoninit, nothing happens. 2: If I subscribe to this behavior subject in my form component class, I still am not passing any data to the rowData variable in my table component. Thanks.

Comment: 1. Sorry about that. I forgot to call the `getData` initially. That needs to be done to get the initial data. I've updated the answer.

2. I didn't suggest you change any implementation in your `FormComponent`.

Comment: Thanks again. It seems like the line in the extractData service: `this.employees.next(body)` is causing problems. Even if I use my `refreshData` function in the `ngOninit`, my data still will not load if `this.employees.next(body)` is present in my service.

Comment: Create a simple StackBlitz project if possible.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! I actually just figured it out. Updated above if you are interested :)

Comment: Mark this as an answer if this helped.